# Do I need to close variables before re-opening them?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, set, variable-names

I'm currently working on an email template that will have multiple content area's. My question is if 1 or more of the content area's are using the same variable will I need to close the variable's in each content block before re-opening them in the next content block.

If I do need to close them what is the code to close a variable, I have tried "unset" "reset" "delete" to no avail.

Comment: You can do reuse them after initialization . No need to close or delete.

Comment: Perfect thank you for your reply that's very helpful, have a great week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reuse the same variable in the template.

Comment: If this is the answer, please mark it as best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly reuse the same variable across different content areas.

However!!!

When one content area is finished, all of the variables it was using will keep their values. This may not be what the next content area expects (or it may be, depending on your need). To "UNSET" a variable when done using it, you can use

```
Var @variable
```

And then it becomes "empty" and ready for the next content area.